# Angular JS remove hash from URL not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying to get rid of the url looking like http://example.com/#/album/0 and have it look more like http://example.com/album/0.

I have the following code

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('chp', ['ngRoute', 'projectControllers']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/directory.html',
        controller: 'ProjectsCtrl'
      }).
      when('/album/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/album.html',
        controller: 'ProjectDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);

var projectControllers = angular.module('projectControllers', []);

projectControllers.controller('ProjectsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.projects = albums;
    $scope.filters = { };
  }]);

projectControllers.controller('ProjectDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$sce',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $sce) {
    $scope.project = albums[$routeParams.id];
})();
```

but this is causing my app the break entirely once I add in $locationProvider in the three places shown. Any idea as to why this is not working for me? Also I am including angular-route.js just after jquery and angular.js so that cant be the problem

Comment: Why would you want to inject `$locationProvider` into all of your controllers? `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` should remove the `/#/`, nothing else needed.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance it looks all right to me, but you must make sure your server is set up to serve `http://example.com/index.html` for any route, otherwise it will try to load `http://example.com/album/0/index.html` before bootstrapping your angular application. What do you see when you enable html5? 404 not found? Console error?

You might also need to add
`<base href="/" />` inside `<head></head>` in your index.html file

Comment: no i see the page still with no errors in the console only it's not loading any of the data like before

Comment: Then maybe Thor Jacobsen is right, are you trying to inject `$locationProvider` in any controller? If so, use `$location` and keep `$locationProvider` only in config.